# Cannot import a custom function from one module into another module

Tags: python, function, import, module

I have the following folder structure:

```
calculator_project
│   __init__.py
│
└───calculator_package
    │   LICENSE
    │   pyproject.toml
    │   README.md
    │   setup.cfg
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───src
    │   └───og_calculator_package
    │           calculator.py
    │           __init__.py
    │
    └───tests
            tests.py
            __init__.py
```

In calculator.py I have the function:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I want to import that function into tests.py. But when I try this:

```
from src.og_calculator_package.calculator import add
```

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Correct version of Python is installed and added to Path.
Pygame is installed.
**init**.py file in every folder